# Setting a manual timeout in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, timeout

I have a vb.net application that interfaces with some external hardware - an array of motor controllers.  To do this, I'm using a CANOpen library provided by the hardware supplier.  However, the timeouts built into the library are frankly excessive, and cause the application to hang painfully under specific conditions.  I'd prefer not to need to edit the library if possible.

What's the most sensible way to design in another, shorter timeout within vb.net?  The function in question is a blocking function, so presumably in-thread timers won't help.  Is there an elegant solution here?

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the library, it's unclear but I wonder whether you could create a subclass of the library and change the duration of the timeouts?

Comment: It would be lovely if I could, but sadly to my level of expertise the library itself is equal parts arcane and baffling.  The timeout duration doesn't seem to be a parameter available for the user to change, and looks hardcoded in.

Comment: I feel your pain. Trying to deal with any specific vendor hardware from within VB is largely a massive pain in the hole, I got that pissed off with trying to talk to AB ControlLogix processors that I eventually wrote my own Ethernet/IP comms driver. Just out of interest, what hardware are you trying to communicate with?

Comment: Ha!  VB looked to be convenient from the outset since all the libraries were out there but it's not always been straightforward.  I'm trying to talk to a pair of rebranded Invertek Optidrive motor VFDs - but specifically these aren't always in use and aren't always powered when the control software is run.  The result is that the thread hangs for 20-30 seconds waiting for the timeouts on establishing the connection, since there's no other means of determining their state. I suppose the serious answer would be to write my own CANOpen 'ping' to check what's on first, but that sounds like effort.

Comment: The brutal truth is that VB _is_ convenient but vendor libraries typically aren't - they'd rather you paid them the equivalent of the UK National Deficit to use their software! Take AB for example, 5k+ for dev licences plus another 3k for runtimes for my current project. Robbing bastards the lot of them. </rant>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, it's is the best I could come up with so far. I've used background workers just because they are easy to use.

Basically it's a thread within a thread which will at least keep your UI responsive, judging by what you've said you should probably use threading for all the drive comms functions anyway in case a drive loses comms for any reason while the app is running.

This ain't pretty, but it will at least allow you to exit out early before the CAN function itself times out.

```
Private connected As Boolean

Private Sub bwTryConnect_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwTryConnect.DoWork
    Dim timeout As Boolean
    Dim timeoutCount As Integer
    Dim timeoutValue As Integer = 5 ' timeout value
    bwConnect.RunWorkerAsync() ' start worker to try connection
    While bwConnect.IsBusy And Not timeout
        Thread.Sleep(1000) ' wait a second
        timeoutCount += 1 ' increment timeout value
        If timeoutCount = timeoutValue Then timeout = True ' connection timed out
    End While
    ' connected will be true if the try connection worker completed (connection to drive ok) before the timeout flag was set, otherwise false
    connected = Not timeout
End Sub

Private Sub bwConnect_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwConnect.DoWork
    ' use your CAN library function here - either a simple connect command or just try reading an arbitary value from the drive
    ' if you want to test this, uncomment one of the following lines:
    'Thread.Sleep(20000) ' simulate timeout
    'Thread.Sleep(2000) ' simulate connect
End Sub
```

Obviously you then call with `bwTryConnect.RunWorkerAsync()`.

Comment: Cheers - I hadn't actually considered laying workers like that previously, that is a little more elegant.  Final solution works great.